# need to customize oracle apex standard region

Tags: oracle-apex

I am Customizing oracle apex 18.2 standard region by copying the standard template with my own custom code

```
DECLARE
l_url VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
l_url := APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(p_url => 'f?p=' || v('APP_ID') || ':30:'||v('APP_SESSION')||'::NO::P29_CHECKOUT:'||:P30_CHECKOUT,
                               p_checksum_type => 'SESSION');

sys.htp.p('<script src="https://test.oppwa.com/v1/paymentWidgets.js?checkoutId="'||:P29_CHECKOUT||'">');
sys.htp.p('</script>');
sys.htp.p('<form action="'||l_url||'" class="paymentWidgets" data-brands="VISA MASTER AMEX">');
sys.htp.p('</form>');
END;
```

I am not able to see this widget in PLSQL Dynamic COntent region
as its an Payment Gateway Widget to Pay after checkout from other page please help how can i show such types of widgets in Dynamic Region

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should use PL/SQL dynamic content instead. The source code will look something like:

```
declare
  PHONE VARCHAR2(20);
  PROFILE VARCHAR2(200);
  SUBSCRIPTIONS VARCHAR2(200);
  SUBSCRIBE VARCHAR2(200);
begin
select COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4,  
into PHONE, PROFILE, SUBSCRIPTIONS, SUBSCRIBE from TABLE
where CONDITIONS;

sys.htp.p(
'<div id="DIV_1">
    <div id="DIV_2">
        <div id="DIV_3">
            <img src="#APP_IMAGES#fav.png" width="70" id="IMG_4" alt='' />
            <div id="DIV_5">
                <p id="P_6">#TITLE#</p>
                <p id="P_7">'|| PHONE || </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DIV_8">
        </div>
        <ul id="UL_9">
            <li id="LI_10">
                <a href="'||PROFILE||'" id="A_11">الملف الشخصي</a>
            </li>
            <li id="LI_12">
                <a href="'||SUBSCRIPTIONS#||' id="A_13">قائمة الاشتراكات</a>
            </li>
            <li id="LI_14">
                <a href="'||SUBSCRIBE||'" id="A_15">إشترك الآن!</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
'
)
```

Comment: Hope this works, don't forget to mark the question as answered if it does

Comment: Sorry your idear actually not working for othere widgets

Comment: It seems you are mixing up between region template and content.
if you wish to use dynamic JS, you can add a button which onClick runs PL/SQL to get data from the DB, and after that changes a page item to contain the prepared JS code, which you can run by using eval($v('P30_JS_CODE_ITEM'))

Comment: can you please share example code in your answer thanks

Comment: Actually i want to integrate this part https://hyperpay.docs.oppwa.com/tutorials/integration-guide/advanced-options